# Mysql query not updating db with .open request while using in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to update a row where I want a checkbox value to update a table field in mysql. I dont want to use form as I dont want the page to refresh. I have pasted the code below and this is the 3rd consecutive day that I am stuck here.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function chkit(uid, chk, sid) {
            chk = (chk==true ? "1" : "0");
            var url = "edit_sms_process.php?userid="+uid+"&chkYesNo="+chk+"&sid="+sid+"";
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            // Use get instead of post.
            req.open("GET", url, true);

            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (req.readyState === 4) {
                    if (req.status === 200) {
                        console.log(req.responseText);

                    } else {
                        console.log("Error", req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };

            req.send(null);
        }
    </script>
```

My php page:

```
 <div class="form-group">

                                       <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"
                                               for="chk_<?php echo $row2['teacher_id']; ?>">SMS Send<span
                                                class="required">*</span>
                                        </label>

                                        <div class="slideThree">
                                            <input type="checkbox"
                                                   name="chk"
                                                   id="chk_<?php echo $row2['teacher_id']; ?>"
                                                   value="chk"
                                            onclick="chkit(<?php echo $row2['teacher_id']; ?>, this.checked, <?php echo $row2['teacher_schoolref_id'] ?>);"
                                                <?php echo ($row2['sms_send'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                                            <label for="chk_<?php echo $row2['teacher_id']; ?>"></label>
```

c

Now the chrome console shows this

> edit_sms.php?sms=61:151 XHR finished loading: GET
>   "http://localhost/cloud_school/cloud_school/dashboard_files/communication/edit_sms_process.php?userid=61&chkYesNo=0&sid=10".chkit
>   @ edit_sms.php?sms=61:151onclick @ edit_sms.php?sms=61:383
>   edit_sms.php?sms=61:143 10success

```
// Get the variables.
$userid = $_GET['userid'];
$chkYesNo = $_GET['chkYesNo'];
$schoolcid= $_GET['sid'];

$sql = "UPDATE teachers SET sms_send = $chkYesNo WHERE teacher_id = $userid AND     teacher_schoolref_code = $schoolcid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if($result==1) {
 echo $result;
 echo $chkYesNo;
 echo "success";
}
```

Eventhough console shows as success, the db is not getting updated. I have included the db connect string in the php page and have not added here for the sake of simplicity.

Any help will be Greatly greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: show updating code here

Comment: <pre> // Get the variables.
$userid = $_GET['userid'];
$chkYesNo = $_GET['chkYesNo'];
$schoolcid= $_GET['sid'];

$sql = "UPDATE teachers SET sms_send = $chkYesNo WHERE teacher_id = $userid AND teacher_schoolref_code = $schoolcid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if($result==1) {
    echo $result;
    echo $chkYesNo;
    echo "success";
}</pre>

Comment: Wrap this code by `isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)` and do `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: HI,

I have done what you said and this is the result and thanks for responding, BTW:

Array
(
    [userid] => 61
    [chkYesNo] => 0
    [sid] => 10
)
11success

Also, CHKYESNO, responds to checkbox status, and I can see the changes in the console

Comment: Okay, I json encoded the array and parsed it, but still the db is not updating. console shows proper data though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay with the help of dod29, I was able to resolve the issue. I was using a wrong column name in the second instance changing which resolved the issue. Thank you dod29